# Multiple Selectors doing the same thing in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
$('.Gallery a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open ($(this).attr('href'),"Gallery","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=500,height=600");
    });
```

basically I want it to also happenin when $('.popup a') is also clicked, how do you have multiple click events do the same thing with different CSS classes.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Why not simply apply a dummy class to the links you want to use, and then apply the selector to the dummy class? AKA Behavior driven javascript.

Comment: Wouldn't you then, assuming client-side manipulation (given the solitary 'jquery' question tag), have to use a multiple selector to apply the dummy class?

Answer (score 2):

You can put two things in the same selector:

```
$('.Gallery a, .popup a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open ($(this).attr('href'),"Gallery","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=500,height=600");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) , [CSS style](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#grouping):

```
$('.Gallery a, .popup a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open ($(this).attr('href'),"Gallery","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=500,height=600");
    });
```